# Prove that if $f$ is differentiable and $f'$ is discontinuous at $c$, $\Rightarrow \nexists \lim_{x \to c^-} f' \lor \nexists \lim_{x \to c^+} f'$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions, derivatives

I'm studying how I can limit the possible discontinuities of the derivative of a function and at a point I want to prove that if $I$ is an interval and $c \in int(I)$:

$f : I \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \phantom{2}$ is differentiable over $I$ and $f'$ is discontinuous on c $\Rightarrow \nexists 
 \lim_{x \to c^-} f' \phantom{2} \lor \phantom{2} \nexists 
 \lim_{x \to c^+} f'$ and both limits are different than $+\infty$ and $-\infty$

but I'm not sure how can I prove it, any suggestions?

Comment: It makes little sense to say that a limit does not exist *and* is different from $\pm\infty$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\lim_{x \to c^+} f' = \lim_{x \to c^-} f' \Rightarrow f(x)$ is differentiable and it's derivative $f'$ is continuous at $x = c$.$Contradiction$

If $\lim_{x \to c^+} f' \ne \lim_{x \to c^-} f' \Rightarrow  f(x)$ is not differentiable and it's derivative $f'$ is discontinuous at $x = c$.

$Contradiction$

If $\lim_{x \to c^+} f' = \pm \infty \lor \lim_{x \to c^-} f'= \pm \infty \Rightarrow  f(x)$ has an infinite derivative at $x = c$ and hence it is non-differentiable there $f'(x)$ is discontinuous at $x=c$

$Contradiction$

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* Try to show the contrapositive: If $L_1:=\lim_{x\to c^-}f'(x)$ and $L_2:=\lim_{x\to c^+}f'(x)$ exist, then $f'(c)=L_1=L_2$.